# Question on pointwise convergence of Sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

In section 8.2 of  textbook "Introduction to real analysis by Bartle" example 8.2.1(c) is as follows:

$f_n : [0,1] →\mathbb{R}$ defined for $n≥2$ by

$$f_n(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
     n^2x & \text{for $0≤x≤1/n$} \\[6pt]
    -n^2(x - 2/n) & \text{ for 1/n≤x≤2/n} \\[6pt]
  0 & \text{for 2/n≤x<1}
   \end{cases}$$

then $f_n$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and hence Riemann integrable______ (upto this i have no problem)

**My problem**$f_n(x)→0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ but i unable to see this...

**My attempt** clearly for $x=0$, $f_n(0)=0$

For $0<x<1/n$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|n^2x|=n^2x$

How, can say this is $<\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$?

Further, for other points $x$ how to establish its convergence and how to show integral of $f_n\text{  from $0$ to $1$}=1$  for $n≥2$

Please help and explain this example 8.2.1(c) in detail.

Comment: If $x$ is fixed, eventually $x > 2/n$ as $n$ increases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed $x \in (0,1]$, there exists  a positive integer $N > 2/x$.

Thus, for all $n \geqslant N$ we have $x > 2/n$ and $|f_n(x)-0| = f_n(x) = 0$.

Comment: sir, so need to use the definition $n^2x$, $-n^2(x-2/n)$ since $x>2/n$ ?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: You are trying to prove pointwise convergence to $0$. You consider a fixed value of $x$ in $(0,1]$. All that matters is for any $\epsilon > 0$ when $n > 2/x$ then $x > 2/n$  and $|f_n(x) - 0| < \epsilon$ -- trivially because $|f_n(x) - 0|  = 0$ for all $n > 2/x$. we don't care about $f_n(x)$ for small $n$ since we are looking at the limit as $n \to \infty$.